# How do I get two things to hit each other and then remove one from the scene?

Tags: swift, enums, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have four colored bars aligned horizontally. I also have some of the exact colors falling from the top of the screen which need to be matched with the bars at the bottom and then removed from the scene on contact. 
(If falling yellow bar hits bottom yellow bar, remove falling yellow bar from the scene)
So, should I have eight different cases for each node in an enum instead of four? This is what it looks like now:

```
enum Bodies: UInt32 {
case blueBar = 1
case redBar = 2
case yellowBar = 4
case greenBar = 8

 }
```

Some of them are not doing what they're supposed to which is why I'm asking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: enum has nothing to do with physics, it's just something you use to give labels to numbers instead of memorizing numbers, you can have just one case there if you want. everything else you want should be adjusted using "categoryBitMask" and other physicsBody properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not considered an enum although I may be able to help. It sounds like you want two things to collide and the one of them to disappear. Try this.

```
let blueBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "name of image")
blueBar.name = "Bluebar"

let fallingBlueBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "name of image")
blueBar.name = "FallingBluebar"

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.node != nil && contact.bodyB.node != nil {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

    if ((firstBody.name == "BlueBar") && (secondBody.name == "FallingBlueBar")) {

         //call the function of what happens when they hit. ex-fall/disappear/explode

        }
    if ((firstBody.name == "FallingBlueBar") && (secondBody.name == "BlueBar")) {

         //call the function of what happens when they hit. ex-fall/disappear/explode


        }
    }
}
```

As far as removing it from the scene. In the same function that we used in each of the if statements above put

```
fallingBlueBar.removeFromParent()
```

Comment: why duplicate functionality?  arrange it so that firstBody is always BlueBar and second is always FallingBlueBar,  the less duplicate code the less chance for error

Comment: This is what I have found to always work in every scenario without there ever being a chance that it will not work.